# Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value issue with Pageable

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, pageable

I am using Spring Data Mongo **Pageable** and **Sonar** giving me below error:

```
Optional<Order> optional = pageable.getSort().stream().findFirst();
if(optional.isPresent()) {
    direction = pageable.getSort().stream().findFirst().get().getDirection();
    property = pageable.getSort().stream().findFirst().get().getProperty();
}

SortOperation sortOperation = Aggregation.sort(direction, property);
```

Error:

> Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value.

I tried few options but nothing is working out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `pageable.getSort().stream()` again inside your `if` statement you are creating a new `Optional` that you need to call `.isPresent()` on.

You should reuse the `Optional` you already have instead of creating the stream over and over, like this:

```
Optional<Order> optional = pageable.getSort().stream().findFirst();
if(optional.isPresent()) {
    direction = optional.get().getDirection();
    property = optional.get().getProperty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But this way I am really struggling to write mockito for the same. Question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135373/optional-cannot-be-returned-by-stream-in-mockito-test-classes